# a parabolic tunnel

Tags: contest-math, quadratics, conic-sections

> A parabolic tunnel has base width 6m, height 4m. Which of these vehicles can fit safely through?
>   coach: 2.9 m high and 4m wide
>   truck: 3.4 m high and 3m wide
>   van: 3.9 m high and 2m wide.

So I set up an equation for parabola with its zeros at $x=+3$ and $x=-3$, which would be $y=-\frac{4}{9}x^2+4$. Then I plugged in $x=2$, $x=1.5$ and $x=1$ in order to find the y values (height of the vehicles). However, I got 2.22, 3, and 3.55 respectively, which means that none of them will fit through.

However, that is not one of the options - there are:

> A) All of them ; B) Coach and Van ; C) Truck and Van ; D) Truck ; E) Van

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Consider rotating the vehicles as well as the vehicles need not touch X -Axis.

Comment: I believe OP has worked the problem correctly. On such examination questions, one should not have to consider preposterous propositions such as the vehicles being transported through the tunnels lying on their sides.

Comment: Why none? The answer is truck and van. Their height fit $3<3.4$ and $3.55<3.9$

Comment: In that case, I think this is a trick question. Note that the truck can almost get through. It just need another 0.1m of height. Flatten its tires a bit will do.

Comment: Everyone, sorry for such a confusion -- the contest authorities have told me that the answer should be "none" -- the answer choices were not correct